# Creating a new object in Java with the class name of an abstract class?

Tags: java, class, object, abstract

I'm working on some exam revision work and created an Employee abstract class and two other classes (AcademicEmployee and ProfessionalEmployee) which extend off of the Employee class.

I have a public static void main set up in the Employee class to run these lines:

```
ProfessionalEmployee boss = new ProfessionalEmployee("The Big Man", 5000.0, null, 10);
AcademicEmployee e1 = new AcademicEmployee("Ryan", 1000.0, boss, 'A');
```

I know you can't instantiate an abstract class and the actual object getting created is whatever comes after the "new" keyword but why am I allowed to do this:

```
Employee boss = new ProfessionalEmployee("The Big Man", 5000.0, null, 10);
```

I'm thinking it works in the way of "Data type" then "Reference name" = new ...

but I'm just confused on why I'm allowed to set the data type to Employee. Sorry if this is a strange question, I'm just new to Java :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a concept of [Polymorphism](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polymorphism-in-java/) in java. Since both of your class `ProfessionalEmployee` and `AcademicEmployee` extends `Employee`, both can be assigned to `Employee` reference object.

Polymorphism allows you define one interface or class and have multiple implementations.

Comment: Is there any downside to assigning them to the Employee reference object?

Comment: The downside is, if you have a method specific to AcademicEmployee or ProfessionalEmployee, you will not be able to invoke it. Because the list of methods available will be based on the reference type.

Comment: Ahh, so an overridden method in either AcademicEmployee or ProfessionalEmployee won't be able to be called on as my reference would only point to methods located within the Employee class?

Comment: @firsttimeandroid no, overridden methods will be invoked as those methods are also present in the parent class. Methods that are created only in the child class that are not in the parent will not be able to invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Your question reads,

> Creating a new object in Java with the class name of an abstract class?

But where have you created a new object like that? You have created two `Object`s as below,

```
 new AcademicEmployee("Ryan", 1000.0, boss, 'A');

new ProfessionalEmployee("The Big Man", 5000.0, null, 10);
```

And, both `AcademicEmployee` and `ProfessionalEmployee` cannot be `abstract` which otherwise you will get a compile-time error.

Since `AcademicEmployee` and `ProfessionalEmployee` **is an** `Employee` (since you have extended/implemented it), you are allowed to assign!

This is explained in simple words [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm)

Comment: Hoo yeah, my question was written a bit strangely. Thanks for the explanation and link though!